# Is it possible to run the puppeteer in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to run the puppeteer in react-native? I have an electron application that uses puppeteer and I would like to make a react-native app.
If there is no possibility of using the puppeteer, would you have a similar one to do this?

Comment: [WebView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/webview) might be an option, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The ideal would be for me to be able to open a browser, as the puppeter does, I need to extract the response